# Magento 1 | how get product attribute data

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, collection, product-collection

Sorry for my English.

I have this code.

```
 $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array(12,4))
        ->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))
        ->setPageSize(500)
        ->load();

    var_dump($productCollection->getData());
```

I need get a product name , and I use this `->addAttributeToSelect('name')` on my collection, but My collection don't return the data.

in attribute settings, I have this

[image]

How can I get all the product data in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending beyond my original answer here are some of the things you can do with product collections. Mixture of filters and functionality to fetch more data.

```
// Load Product Collection
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
// only products which are visible in frontend
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
// Only Enabled products remain in the collection
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
// Only products that are in stock
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
// Add All Product Attributes
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
// Add Individual Product Attributes
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name', 'description', 'brand');
// Add Specific Price Attributes
$collection->addMinimalPrice();
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->addTaxPercents();
// Add Category IDs to Products
$collection->addCategoryIds();
// Add Tier Pricing Info
$collection->addTierPriceData();
// Add Product URL Rewrites
$collection->addUrlRewrite();
// Or (Wrong?)
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array('status', 'status'),
    array(array('neq' => 1), array('null' => true))
)
// Or
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'download_link',
        'null'      => true,
    ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'download_link',
        'eq'        => '',
    ),
));
// Filter Collection
// Is Equal To
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
// Is Not Equal To
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));
// Greater Than
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 3));
// Less Than
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt' => 3));
// Greater Than or Equal To
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => 4));
// Less Than or Equal To
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => 4));
// Contains – with % wildcards
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'DVD%'));
// Does Not Contain – with % wildcards
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => 'ABC%'));
// In Array
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array(1,3,12)));
// Not In Array
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array(1,2,12)));
// Is NULL
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('description', 'null');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('description', array('null' => true));
// Is Not NULL
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('description', 'notnull');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('description', array('notnull' => true));
// Further Filtering
// Filter by Product IDs
$collection->addIdFilter(array(4,5,6));
// Filter by Current Store
$collection->addStoreFilter();
// Filter by Current Website
$collection->addWebsiteFilter();
// Filter by Category
$collection->setStoreId($id)->addCategoryFilter($category)
// Sort Collection
// er by Attribute Ascending
$collection->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
// er by Attribute Descending
$collection->setOrder('name', 'DESC');
// Random Order
$collection->setOrder('rand()');
// Limit Collection
$collection->setPageSize(10);
$collection->setCurPage(1);
// Count Results
$collection->count();
// Return Only Product IDs
$collection->getAllIds();
// Debug Collection
$collection->getSelect();
// Static type strings
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL
Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$collection
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array(12,4))
        ->joinField(
            'qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))
        ->setPageSize(500)
        ->load();
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. ->addAttributeToSelect does not work at all